# How to increase system.img partition size

Tags: android, android-source

I'm building a custom aosp image to which I want to add gapps after flashing.

There is not enough space in the system.img partition (500mb short) to accommodate gapps so the operation fails.

My question is where do I specify system.img partition size in the aosp tree?

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, for other people looking for an answer for this, it is impossible to change the partition size for `system.img`. It is defined as part of `BoardConfig.mk` and is static for the device.

In theory, it may be possible to increase `system.img` size by altering the parameter `BOARD_SYSTEMIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE` and reducing other partition sizes, but I guess that would fail if the partitions are on different physical devices.

See for example `device/samsung/manta/BoardConfig.mk`

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT actually true. It's system.img is an linux ext4 file system and you can resize it from uBuntu using the following command:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=128 >> system.img  
e2fsck -f system.img  
resize2fs system.img
```

Now, you added 128 MB to system.img!

David

Comment: think it is YAFFS and not EXT4, which requires other commands.

Comment: You will not be able to use a system.img partition larger than the one defined in BoardConfig. The question is not about how to realize ext4 or a sparse image

Comment: Instead of do the dd command to system.img, first convert the system.img to a raw image :)